# Pass .js databases as a prop to a React Native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I currently have an image slideshow showing up on my app. I first initialized the images in a `images.js` file.

```
export default [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: require("../AS_images/1.webp"),
  },
```

then I import this file as a dependency in my component `Slider.js`

`import Images from "../assets/AS_images/images";`

then I use it to render a flatlist and deal with the rest in a different component

```
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={Images}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <SlideItem item={item} />}
     etc..
```

then this is being displayed in `App.js`  by calling the main component

```
<SafeAreaView>
    <Slider />
  </SafeAreaView>
```

It works great, but I have 8 sets of image slideshows I need to display, and I don't really want to create 7 more Slider.js files for each individual. I'd rather want to pass a prop that would tell the component which set of images to use. For example:

```
<SafeAreaView>
<Slider path="Set2"/>
</SafeAreaView>
```

and in the Slider.js file, unpon receiving this prop it would adapt the routing accordingly:

`import Images from "../assets/Set2/images";`

The only part of the path that would need to be changed is the "Set2" bit. I plan to bundle all my images in their own separate folders under /assets/ and then within their respective folder to have this database that initializes them /assets/Set2/images.js

How would I go about doing that or doing something similar? Thank you in advance for your help.

I tried modifying import pathing and location but that obviously didn't work

Current Code
App.js

```
  <SafeAreaView>
        <Slider path="AS" />
      </SafeAreaView>
```

Slider.js

```
import AS from "../assets/AS_images/images";
```

...

```
return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={props.path}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <SlideItem item={item} />}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        snapToAlignment="center"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={handleOnScroll}
        onViewableItemsChanged={handleOnViewableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
      />
      <Pagination data={props.path} scrollX={scrollX} index={index} />
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to import all the images and, based on the Slider props, return the set of images?

Comment: Hmm, so import all the images as dependencies and pass a prop such as 1 or 2. And when Slider.js receives..say number 1 it will take fom the first set. Something like

If(props.set === 1) {
        data={Set1}
}
or something similar?

Comment: Yeah , try with `data={props.set == 1 ? Set1 : Set2`

Comment: That sounds great in theory but when I pass props.path it seems to be ok for the first line but then I am passing the same data into another component and then it throws an error about .map.
Here's how the component looks `<Pagination data={props.path} scrollX={scrollX} index={index} />`

Comment: its seens that the .map is been used in a variable that is not a list , please update the question with your current code

Comment: You can now check the code in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `data="AS"` , not the AS files, this should work

```js
import AS from "../assets/AS_images/images";
import BS from "../assets/BS_images/images";
const Slider = (props) => {
    return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={props.path == "AS" ? AS : BS }
        renderItem={({ item }) => <SlideItem item={item} />}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        snapToAlignment="center"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={handleOnScroll}
        onViewableItemsChanged={handleOnViewableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
      />
      <Pagination data={props.path} scrollX={scrollX} index={index} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

`

Comment: I set the data prop from the Pagination component to have the same boolean as in the FlatList component and now it does work. 
I just have one more question though, I have 8 slideshows to display, does that mean that my boolean will look like this? data={props.path == "AS" ? AS : BS : CS : DS : ES : FS, etc? }

Comment: create a dict like, `const pathDataMapping = {"AS": AS,....}` and do `data={pathDataMapping[props.set]}`